# How to create user controllable slide show in html using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a slide show html page for any mobile devices using above mentioned technologies.I google alot but every sol that i found is not user controllable  . Those slideshows have timeout and they keep changing after mentioned time out period. I want that it should be manual like if user have trackball/pad or touch enabled device the change in slide only occur when user touches screen or uses his/her trackball/pad. And one important thing the slide show images should get aligned to any device resolution automatically.

Any help will be appreciated.

mrana...

here is one example 
           
           
            
           
           
           Automated slide show

### Automated slide show

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var image1=new Image()

      image1.src="http://abc.com/imags/logo/image1.png"

      var image2=new Image()

      image2.src="http://abc.com/imags/logo/image2.png"

        var image3=new Image()

       image3.src="http://abc.com/imags/logo/image3.png"

      var image4=new Image()

     image4.src="http://abc.com/imags/logo/image4.png"

     var image5=new Image()

     image5.src="http://abc.com/imags/logo/image5.png"

     </script>

     </head>

    <img src="http://abc.com/imags/logo/image1.png" name="img" width="400" height="600" />

  <script>

  var step=1

  function slideImages(){

  if (!document.images)

   return

  document.images.img.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

  if (step<5)

  step++

 else

step=1

 setTimeout("slideImages()",3000)

 }

slideImages()

</script>

 </html>
```

Comment: So remove the `setTimeout()` and add an event handler for click or touch or scroll (or whatever).

Comment: Request you to post some template code and how about the autofit to any kinda screen resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of ways and examples on google , who can help to make user controllable slideshow.
for example look at [this](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/) example, , u will get source code also with explanation.